# Is it possible to save a CharSequence in Firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, charsequence

Is possible to save a `CharSequence` variable into `Firebase`?

Checked out: [Supported Data Types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types), but `charsequence` is not there...

I'm getting serializable problems related to this, tried: pro-guard rules, public attributes, implements serializable, etc; but I'm not able to save `charsequence` into `Firebase`.

Is anyone able to help me out with this?

PS: it needs to be a **`charsequence`**, *not a string*!

Answer (score 1):

You can save a CharSequence to Firestore by converting it to a String with its [toString()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/CharSequence.html#toString()) method.  If you read the string back from Firestore, it will be a String object, which implements CharSequence as well.  You will not be able to use automatic serialization with a CharSequence interface. The SDK won't know which implementation of CharSequence to create for you when you read the data back out.

Comment: Ok, we can say that a String is a type of Charsequence, but I'm not asking this way, because i'm trying to use SpannableString and i need to store in firebase a text with its mark ups, do u understand?Because i need to retrieve data with it's mark ups...

Comment: OMG,man...what can i do? (o_O)'', i'm getting serializable error whe i try to store a Charsequence =(

Comment: Yes, read my answer again.  You can't do that.  Convert it to a String first.

Answer (score 0):

To store markup text(or CharSequence) in database(may be Firestore) you may use `Html.toHtml(Spanned text)` function from `android.text.Html` class which return styled html string. To retrieve markup text back use `Html.fromHtml(String html)`. You may find android reference [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html).